# 1 single row of cells, i want to copy it into multiple rows of 10 cells each

Tags: vba, excel

in excel i have a very long row of values that were imported into excel.

For simplicity sake, lets say i have 1 row with 100 cells with values of 1 to 100.
I was wondering if there was an easy way to copy it so that it would result in a table 10x10 with row 1 being 1 to 10, row 2: 11 to 20, etc

I tried using the offset function but was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use vba (assuming the row of 100 numbers is row 20)

```
for i = 1 to 10
  for j = 1 to 10
    cells(i, j) = cells(20, j + 10 * (i - 1))
  next j
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want accurate help, please provide a sample of what you've done so we can assist, rather than expecting us to code this for you.  Still, this is a fairly simple snippet based on what you are asking for:

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets(1).Activate
For i = 1 To 10
    Range(Cells(1, (i * 10) - 9), Cells(1, (i * 10))).Copy
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial
Next i
```

This copies from the top-most row of the first sheet and makes it a 10x10 matrix on the second sheet.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I apologize I´m a newbie a to both the forum and I had never used vba so i wasn´t sure where to start I had attempted to use formulas, and had used the offset fucntion as follows: =OFFSET($A$1,0,(ROWS($1:1)-1+10*(COLUMNS($A4:A4)-1))) . however that was giving me the transpose of what i wanted , that is column one was 1 through 10 as opposed to row 1 being 1 through 10  and i had tried playing around wiht it but had been able to get what i was hoping for and wasnt sure where to go next. anyways, thanks for the help and again sorry for the faux pas

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to deal with this problem without macros:

1. Create an offset value in your column and row heading
2. Combine the offset value of the row and the column to get you total offset.
3. Use this value to retrieve the proper cell using =OFFSET(...

Alternatively, refer to this post to do it with a VBA Macro.
https://superuser.com/questions/700104/transpose-data-in-columns-to-rows-downwards

Answer (score 0):

**Without VBA:**

If you have data in the first row, then pick a cell, say cell **B3** and enter this formula:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,1,(10*ROWS($1:1)-10)+(COLUMNS($A:A)))
```

Then copy **B3** from **B4** to **B11**

Then copy **B3** thru **B11** downwards

Here is an example::

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

Both VBA and non-VBA solutions will work as shown in other answers. A simpler non-VBA formula (doesn't need the values in row 1) is:

```
=(ROW()-1)*10+COLUMN()
```

That assumes your data starts in A1. If your starting cell is say D4, you could also do something like:

```
=(ROW()-ROW($D$4))*10+COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$4)+1
```